# How to add a placeholder to a select element via JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select>` element that is being generated dynamically. It does not have a placeholder by default. I want to add a placeholder to it via `JavaScript` or `jQuery`. How can I do that?

I have a sample code setup here:

```js
/* var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('select.selectName.form-control');

var elemJQuery = $('.ownerName.form-control');
// console.log(elemJQuery);
$('.ownerName.form-control').attr("placeholder", "One"); */

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select.ownerName.form-control').attr("placeholder", "One");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectName form-control" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible">
  <option value></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menus don't have placeholders. The normal approach is to put the placeholder in the text of the first option, which is selected by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select.selectName.form-control option:first-child').text("One");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectName form-control" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible">
  <option value></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="selectName form-control" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible">
  <option value></option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="d">D</option>
  <option value="e">E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you. This worked. What if I have multiple tables on the page with different `id` values, and each table has the same `select` element? I want set the placeholder for all the selects in all the tables. This will not work, but something like `$('#' + tableId + '.select.selectName.form-control option:first').text("One");` where `tableId` is a variable that contains the value.

Comment: I've updated it to use `:first-child` so it will match the first option in each dropdown.

Comment: Barmar, thank you for the prompt reply. It worked for all tables, except the empty tables, and tables with just 1 row in it. For tables with 1 row, after you select the option for that 1 value from the `select`, this placeholder text now shows up in the `dropdown`. Earlier, it is not showing up. For empty tables, the placeholder is not showing up at all.

Comment: Do we need to add something like `selected` and `disabled` as `attributes`?

Comment: The first option is selected by default. You could add disabled if you want.

Comment: But this first option is initially not showing up for tables with no rows, or just 1 row. It shows up after you select the other option from the list in case of table with 1 row. 

Other tables are fine if it has more than 1 rows.

Answer (score 0):

while generating the select dynamically add the first option disabled then add the other list I don't know how you generating the select element I hope this will helped you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select class="selectName form-control" id="slct" style="width: 100%; 
visibility: visible">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is about a dropdown menu, not a text input.